# Sort array on multiple properties and then update a property based on previous item

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to create tvProgram List app.
I need function to adjust cell size of tvProgram.

input

```
[
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T06:00:00", distanceFromTop: 6},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T06:30:00", distanceFromTop: 9},
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T07:00:00", distanceFromTop: 9}, 
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T07:30:00", distanceFromTop: 18},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 13},
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 15}
]
```

output:

```
[
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T06:00:00", distanceFromTop: 6},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T06:30:00", distanceFromTop: 9},
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T07:00:00", distanceFromTop: 10},
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T07:30:00", distanceFromTop: 18},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 19},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 19}
]
```

I want to add 1 to distanceFromTop, according to below conditions.

1. "start" must be sorted.
2. "distanceFromTop" must be sorted.
3. if there are same "start" object, distanceFromTop are also same.
4. don't reduce distanceFromTop, just add 1.

```
  // wrong
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 13}, // 13 !== 15
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 15}
  distanceFromTop must be also same.
  // correct
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 15}, // 15 === 15
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 15}
```

```
ideal data
const ideal = [
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T06:00:00", distanceFromTop: 6},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T06:30:00", distanceFromTop: 9},
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T07:00:00", distanceFromTop: 10},
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T07:30:00", distanceFromTop: 18},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 19},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 19}
]
```

How to create this function

```
ideal = func(ideal)
```

I tried below code.

```
const isSorted = (arr) => {
    var len = arr.length - 1;
    for(var i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if(arr[i].distanceFromTop > arr[i+1].distanceFromTop) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

const func = (arr) => {
  output = arr.slice()
  while (isSort(ideal)) {
    addOne(ideal)
  }

  return output
}
```

Please tell me how to write addOne method.

Comment: It's not clear. What do you mean by `I want to add 1`? If two items have the same `start` value, and have the different `distanceFromTop`, then update `distanceFromTop` to be the same. Which object's `distanceFromTop` should be taken? If two items have the same `start` but have different `channel`, then are they considered as matching data? You should provide one input and output that covers your scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `sort` the array by `start` and then by `distanceFromTop`. Then, you could do something like this using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Logic to get the new `distanceFromTop`:

- Get the `last` item in the accumulator
- If the current item's `start` is same as `last.start`, then use `last.distanceFromTop`
- Else, check if the current `distanceFromTop` > `last.distanceFromTop`
- If yes, keep it as it is. Add it to the accumulator
- Else, use `last.distanceFromTop + 1`

```js
const input = [
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T06:00:00", distanceFromTop: 6},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T06:30:00", distanceFromTop: 9},
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T07:00:00", distanceFromTop: 9}, 
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T07:30:00", distanceFromTop: 18},
  {channel: "y", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 13},
  {channel: "x", start: "2019-01-08T08:00:00", distanceFromTop: 15}
]

const sorted = input.sort((a, b) => a.start.localeCompare(b.start) 
                                || a.distanceFromTop - b.distanceFromTop);
                                
const output = sorted.reduce((acc, { channel, start, distanceFromTop }) => {
     if (acc.length === 0)
       return [{channel,start,distanceFromTop}];

     const last = acc[acc.length - 1];
     const newDistanceFromTop = last.start === start 
                                 ? last.distanceFromTop 
                                 : distanceFromTop > last.distanceFromTop 
                                 ? distanceFromTop 
                                 : last.distanceFromTop + 1;

     return [...acc, { channel, start, distanceFromTop: newDistanceFromTop}];
  }, [])

console.log(output)
```